# Rubbing disc brake caliper

Tags: brakes, rotor

Finally I bought my new hydraulic disc brakes (Shimano M-446) and installed it on my bike . It was a little difficult to adjust the calipers  , because the space between the pads is smaller than on my previous brakes (Hayes Stroker Ryde). But finally I had managed to align them properly and went for a test ride . When I sat on my bike I heard the rotors rubbing but only on cornering and turns . I got out of it and rotated the wheel but everything was OK when. What a mystery ? Why the rotors are rubbing only when I am sitting on the bike ?

Answer (score 2):

There could be some play in the axles. Lift the wheel and try to wiggle. Another explanation might be a 'soft' fork. Also check the tightening of the quick releases, a quarter turn of the nut might bring some change.

Comment: Axles should have small amount of play in them when not done up. Tightening the QR removes this play and properly preloads the bearings. If the QR is not tight enough the play will still be there.

Comment: Depends whether the play is in the dropouts or the bearings. Play in the dropouts can cause this, and the solution is, like Carel said, to tighten the QR.

Answer (score 1):

How much do you weigh? What fork do you have? What wheel set do you have?

It could be one or more of the following:

- QR/Axle isn't tight enough
- Rotors aren't tightened to proper spec
- calipers aren't tightened to proper spec
- the fork is flexing
- the wheel is flexing

I'm a heavier rider (+/- 230lbs) and I ran into this problem early on with XC/trail spec wheels and forks to the point it really held me back from progressing as a rider. If you are more than say 190lbs you need to approach bike/component selection differently. Remember: cheap, light, strong - pick 2.